# The fastest programming language for scraping dynamic sites

Tags: parsing, web, web-scraping, programming-languages

I write the site parser on `Python` (I pull data from the pages, process it, perform various arithmetic operations that are generated with `js`). I use `selenium` + pure `lxml` where it is possible. But I am not happy with the performance.

I want  write on the other `programming language`, more quickly. Only I do not know which one to choose.

Someone writes that `Scala` does everything, someone says that `C++` (not even `C`), someone for `Assembler`, someone for `Rust`, `Perl`, `PHP`... In general, I'm confused ... What faster parses a `dynamic site`?

Comment: The answer is node, since whatever other language you choose, it's going to have to convert things to javascript to communicate with the browser context. Also any synchronous language won't be able to handle events so you end up resorting to polling for DOM changes, etc.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes you are right. But I'm interested in which language supports asynchrony, parallelism? Which language processes the data from a dynamic website faster?

Comment: If by dynamic you mean javascript-rendered, the answer is javascript, obviously. Otherwise I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the pages being scraped are not in your local network (and maybe even if they are, depending on how they are generated), it's likely that the slowest part of your scrape will be waiting for the page to be sent over the network.

Since you're scraping multiple pages, the simplest way of speeding up the process is to scrape multiple pages in parallel, so that it is not necessary to wait for one page to finish before you start downloading the next one.

Any language which allows parallel processing would work, but even if the language doesn't support it, you could run several scraping processes in parallel using a standard shell.

Comment: But if I do parallel work at `Perl` (f.e), it will be faster than at `Python`, will it not?

Comment: @pythoner: that's almost entirely dependent on you perl and python coding abilities.